# Replacing each instance of ">" with ">{InstanceNumber}_"

Tags: parsing, awk, sed

A quick background on `.fasta` files, every other line starting from the first begins with `>`, after which we have the header name. There are no other places in the file where we can find `>`. Since sometimes merging 2 fasta files can lead to non-unique header names, I wanted a simple script that makes each header name unique.

I have:

```
for i in {1..4013}; do awk '/>/{c++;if(c=='"$i"'){sub(">",">'"$i"'_")}}1' Combined_Pass_2D_nanocorrect_round1_renamed.fasta > tmp.fasta; \ 
rm -rf Combined_Pass_2D_nanocorrect_round1_renamed.fasta; \ 
mv tmp.fasta Combined_Pass_2D_nanocorrect_round1_renamed.fasta; done
```

You can probably guess that this is taking ages, but it does the trick. I used `grep -c` to find the number of headers, and determined it was 4013.

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: Could you add same example lines, what they look before the transformation and how they should look like after the transformation?

Comment: Every time you write a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach goes through the whole fasta file for every single replacement. For an input file like this:

```
>header
ATGC
>another header
TACG
>and still another header
ATCG
```

You can use awk directly:

```
$ awk '/^>/{sub(/^>/, sprintf(">%04d_", ++i))}1' infile.fasta
>0001_header
ATGC
>0002_another header
TACG
>0003_and still another header
ATCG
```

I've added zero padding to the number. If you don't want that, you have to remove `04` from the `sprintf` statement.

This command just checks if a line starts with `>`, and if it does, it increments a counter, appends it to the `>`, adds an underscore and prints the line (the lone `1` at the end of the command).